# Neo4j returning "Error: undefined - undefined"

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm not too familiar with Neo4j/Cypher. I have been researching where this error could be coming from, but I'm stumped. Note that this has been run on another computer and has been successful, but not on mine.

Here's my input (indices already exist):

```
WITH
  range(2016, 2016) AS YEARS, range(6,6) AS MONTHS, range(7,10) as Days,
  range(0,23) as Hours, range(0,59) as Minutes, range(0,59) as Seconds
FOREACH(year IN YEARS |
  CREATE (y:Year {yearid: year})
  FOREACH(month IN MONTHS |
    CREATE (m:Month {monthid: month})
    MERGE (y)-[:HAS_MONTH]->(m)
    FOREACH(day IN Days |
      CREATE (d:Day {dayid: day})
      MERGE (m)-[:HAS_DAY]->(d)
      FOREACH(hour IN Hours |
        CREATE (h:Hour {hourid: hour})
        MERGE (d)-[:HAS_HOUR]->(h)
        FOREACH(minute IN Minutes |
          CREATE (mm:Minute {minuteid: minute})
          MERGE (h)-[:HAS_MINUTE]->(mm)
          FOREACH(second IN Seconds |
            CREATE (ss:Second {secondid: second})
            MERGE (mm)-[:HAS_SECOND]->(ss)))))));
```

Comment: do you really want, do you really really want a node for each second ?
Maybe this is not the tool you are looking for (look for time series db) or maybe you just need a timestamp property somewhere

Comment: also, I was unsure about multilevel FOREACH. But it worked.
Added 351462 labels, created 351462 nodes, set 351462 properties, created 351461 relationships, completed after 33017 ms.

Comment: To speed this query up a bit, all the `MERGE`s should be `CREATE`s, since all the nodes are newly created anyway. But this probably has nothing to do with the Error.

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using for this?